# antonymes qui sont aussi homonymes

Tags: antonyme, homonymes

J'ai parlé [ailleurs](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31649/antonyms-yet-homophones) d'antonymes qui sont homophones. On m'a dit qu'il s'agissait d'auto-antonymes ou contranymes.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_contranyms) en a quelques-uns en francais. Je pensais aussi à 'sanctionner'. Avec l'article on a aussi 'la pesanteur', 'l'apesanteur'. D'autres idées ?

Comment: On peut dire que c'est « terrible » ce genre de question…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je dirais même plus, c’est «trop», ce genre de question...

Answer (score 1):

J'ai trouvé une [page dédiée](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Mots_ayant_deux_sens_antonymes_en_fran%C3%A7ais) sur le Wiktionnaire.

On y trouve par exemple **apprendre**, **louer**, **remercier**.

Je me souviens aussi d'une page wikipedia sur des curiosités linguistiques en français (avec un paragraphe sur le sujet), je la mettrai si je la retrouve.

Answer (score 0):

Il y aurait par exemple :

> - **amateur** : "un *amateur* de grands vins" (il s'y connait bien dans ce domaine); "T'es vraiment un *amateur*" (un novice)

A part ceux qui sont déjà sur wikipedia, je n'ai pas d'autres idées pour l'instant, j'en rajouterai au fur et à mesure.